# How to copy multiple using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am beginner in shell script i am trying to copy multiple files. I want manually give the input how i change my code

```
echo "Please Enter File Name"
      read b
      cp -l ~/Downloads/"{$b,$b,$b,$b,$b}" ~/myProj/image
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what you mean by "I want manually give the input how i change my code."
But try this :

```
  echo "Please Enter File Name"
  read b
  for i in $b
  do
      cp -l ~/Downloads/$i ~/myProj/image
  done
```

Comment: Why have you got a loop for a single variable ?

Comment: As i understood it, it was a variable `b` with multiple files inserted from user input so i thought it would be a good and understandable way to treat it. But if you have an easier way, i'll take it. Always wanting to learn new tricks :D.

Comment: @Throngar no that's probably a fair interpretation of OPs question, just wondering :)